# how to indicate to click on title for more information

Tags: buttons, discovery, header

im designing an app and am having trouble indicating to the user to click on the business name('candys' in this case) for more information. clicking shows details like contact details, website etc. its for android and iphone so i would prefer it to be cross platform, however if there is a better solution i would love to hear it.

the header

[image: my header]

.

my idea(dont really like)

[image: my header]

any ideas ux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but I would recommend against using an icon like the one you have chosen (which could be platform specific). The concept of `more information` is a bit abstract to represent with an icon that can easily translate across cultures.

**Option 1**

If the information is to be shown in a overlay panel, then a downward arrow should be suitable: 
[image]

This approach is how StackExchange displays more user information quickly in an overlayed panel:

[image]

Unless clicking the company name does something else, I would make clicking the company name or the arrow show the overlay panel.

If the arrow is not clear enough, I would add some text. Note that clicking `more info` or the arrow should trigger the overlay panel:

[image]

**Option 2**

If the infromation is to be on it's own screen in the application, then it is better to just be explicit and use a button:

[image]

In this case, there is no mistake and confusion as to how the user can get more information about the company. You should also style the button to suit your application.

Comment: i like the option 1 downwards arrow, that would be quite suitable.

Comment: I like option 1 thought I feel it suggests a menu will pop out rather than info. Maybe an italic I might be useful as a cross-culture multi-lingual option?

Comment: the arrow down is nice, however only for a drop-down menu... if you're linking to another page, this would not suite here...